# Menu item in Ext-JS4

Tags: extjs

I am new to Ext-JS4. I am working on a project in which I am configuring a toolbar. I have added few buttons to the toolbar, one of which has a menu and the menu basically has a grid which is loaded from a JSON store. The grid is used within the menu due to such requirement in the project. The grid is loaded properly but I need access to the menu item being clicked within the menu. I want the text of the menu item which is clicked. The following code will better explain my question.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId : 'favStore',
    model : favModel,
    autoLoad : true,
    groupField : 'group_header',
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : '../../data/favorites.json',
        reader : {  
            type : 'json',
            root : 'favoritesMenu'
        }
    }   
});


var favGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store : store,
        columns : [{
            dataIndex : 'listItem',
            width : 200
        }],
        features : [groupingFeature],
        width : 200,
        height : 275,
        autoHeight : true,
        border : false
});

var favMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    items : [favGrid],
    listeners : {
        'click' : function(store,item) {
            alert('Item clicked= ');//tried item.text here but not working
        }
    }
});
```

In the alert method on the click event I want the text of the menu item clicked. I hope I am clear with the question. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Also can anyone suggest me some good blogs on Ext-JS4?

All these things are defined within the initComponent method of Ext.define() for toolbar.

Comment: Which type is your menu items?

Comment: You want the grid rows would work like menu items? You can assign listener to grid instead of the menu using "itemclick" event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the documentation.
For me it was very usefull:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your case you want the listener to be attributed to your grid, not the menu.  Something like...

```
var favGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  store : store,
  columns : [{
    dataIndex : 'listItem',
    width : 200
  }],
  features : [groupingFeature],
  width : 200,
  height : 275,
  autoHeight : true,
  border : false,
  listeners: {
    'itemclick': function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
      //Assuming 'name' is a fieldname in the record
      alert('item clicked = ' + record.get('name')); 
    }
  }
});
```

Check out the Ext.grid.Panel documentation here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel .  Click on "events" at the top and find "itemclick".

Comment: The problem is solved by using the record.get(//id here) method. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the solution to show the record.get() specifically.  Please mark as answer if this answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

or you can have your menu listen to the grid's event by relaying the events.

```
favMenu.relayEvents(favGrid, ['itemclick']);
favMenu.on('itemclick', me.onFavFunction, me);
```